# How can I prevent all notifications from a given Facebook user?

Tags: facebook

I have this one FB friend updates too often. I "unsubscribed" from him so his updates no longer show up on my news feed, but every time I visit FB the "world" icon in the upper left has a number (such as 368,000) superimposed on it and it will mostly be updates from this one guy.

Is there any way I can remain FB friends with him but **completely** hide his activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that he is not on your Close Friends list; you will receive a notification for almost everything that one of your Close Friends does unless you turn off notifications for Close Friends.  Also if he is posting to a group, make sure that you have notifications turned off for the group.

Comment: OK, I'll give that a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what mark4o has already said, I would suggest that you move him to your "Restricted Friends" List. Also, if you are having 368,000 notifications from a single guy, there surely is something wrong.

Comment: I was kidding about that. But yes, you are right. There's definitely something wrong.